# color change on ggplot only one bar

Tags: ggplot2

I am trying to fill the color of only one bar (any color is fine).
Here is my code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(true_normal), y = behavior_ch)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Not normal", "Normal")) +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar",
              fun.data = mean_se,
              width = 0.2) +
  stat_summary(aes(label = sprintf("%0.2f", round(..y.., digits = 2))),
           geom = "text",
           fun.data = mean_se,
           position = position_nudge(y = -0.2)) +
  ylim(0, 1) +
  labs(x = "Feeling when interacting with Law enforcement",
       y = "Behavior change")
```

I have tried adding fill= area but it give me an error

Comment: Which bar are you trying to highlight?  I would expect from your `scale_x_...()` code you have two bars: "Not normal" and "Normal".  If you want to color code on that, you can try `aes(fill=true_normal)`, but it's difficult to say without more information.

Comment: Can you share an example of your data using `dput()`, and describe how the plot you create using the code above should be different?